# How to update maven pom dynamically

Tags: maven, wsimport, maven-invoker-plugin

I am using wsImport to create java atrifacts from wsdl files. I have many wsdl files, as of now I am making multiple entries of wsimport plugin in pom for  wsdl files which becomes messy.

Is it possible to add plugins to maven dynamically at run time? 
I am able to invoke maven commands from java with maven embedder and maven-invoker.
I am also able to read pom using MavenXpp3Reader but completely unsure about updating pom on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [JAX-WS Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/) instead.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <target>2.1</target>
                <!-- use 2.2 for Java SE 8 or Java EE 6+ runtime -->
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>...</wsdlUrl>
                    <wsdlUrl>...</wsdlUrl>
                    <wsdlUrl>...</wsdlUrl>
                    ...
                </wsdlUrls>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Refer to the linked documentation for more configuration options.

Be aware that this generates source files in `target/generated-sources/wsimport` which get automatically added to the source files to be compiled by the `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Comment: I want to put artifacts of different wsdls in different packages. Is there any way of adding wsdls to pom dynamically at run time?